# fix height and width of all images added dynamically to image view

Tags: android

I have horizontal scroll view in which i have to add images which are coming from server **which are shown of equal size in height and width**.
how to set height and width with centre zooming of image

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [DynamicHeightImageView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/etsy/android/grid/util/DynamicHeightImageView.java). You have to explicitly give the with of the imageview here and height will be set by `setHeightRatio()` method. You can use `scaleType` as `centerCrop` on imageView or if you want to use the zooming you can use any zooming animation.